# Jquery is autoclicking

Tags: jquery

I have got this html

```
<div class="tagc">
    <p class='HidTagc'>Hide</p>
    <p class='tpt'>Tagged people</p>
</div>
```

And this jquery

```
        $(".HidTagc").click(function(event) {
            $(this).parent().css({'border-bottom':"1px solid"});
            $(this).siblings().css('border-bottom', '0');
            $(this).html("Show").addClass('showt');
        });
        $(".tagc").delegate('.showt', 'click', function() {
            $(this).parent().css({'border-bottom':"0"});
            $(this).siblings().css('border-bottom', '1px solid'); 
        });
```

So the problem is when i click "Hide" it works perfectly but as soon as it changes css to `'border-bottom':"1px solid"` one second after it auto changes 
to `'border-bottom':"0"` which is i think because of this line

```
$(this).html("Show").addClass('showt');
```

So how can i make this work properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stop the event from bubbling,

```
 $(".HidTagc").click(function(event) {
   event.stopPropagation();
```

to stop that from happening. `.tagc` is a parent of `.HidTagc`. So whenever you clicks on `.HidTagc`, the event will be propagated to `tagc` also.